# How to get a list of folders inside multiple folders with python

Tags: python

I've tried a few codes and they all give me the list of my root directory folders or all the files/ folders within a tree. I'm wondering how you get a list of just folders inside folders from your root directory?

Codes I've tried:
This gives me the base list of folders from my root directory.

```
(next(os.walk(root))[1])
```

how do I get folders from the next level down? If I try

```
(next(os.walk(root))[2])
```

that gives me all the way down to the file.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to recursively traverse the file structure and get a flat list from it? Just to make sure I understand.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [os.walk() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), `os.walk()` returns a 3-tuple of `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)` and functions as an iterable. In python, this means that it may be used as the second operand of a for loop i.e. as the iterable in the syntax

```
for identifier in iterable:
    [some operation with "identifer" for each element of "iterable"]
```

In the case of `os.walk()`, we can easily construct a list of all folders with

```
import os

def get_all_folders(path):
    folder_list = []
    for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(path):
        folder_list += list(dnames)
    return folder_list


print(get_all_folders(os.getcwd()))
```

Or, using the more succinct list comprehension with [itertools.chain()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import os

def get_all_folders(path):
    return list(chain(*[dir_list for _, dir_list, _ in os.walk(path)]))


print(get_all_folders(os.getcwd()))
```